# Adding key and mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jframe, keyevent

I tried to add key and mouse listener to JFrame, it didn't work, also i find out that JFrame can't get focus. I have a function which loads the buffered image where i want to add the mouse and key listener in entire image dimension.

```
  public void imageloader(BufferedImage image) throws InterruptedException {

        // frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension dimension = new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
        label.removeAll(); //label is Jlabel
        label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        frame.setSize(dimension);
        label.revalidate();
        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(label,
                ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,
                ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.getContentPane().add(pane);
        frame.setSize(dimension);
       // frame.setVisible(true);


    }
```

How can be mouse and key listener be added to this image frame without moving parts from this function?

Comment: please are you `tired` or `tried`

Comment: hehehe you questions talks about 1st. from options :-), thanks for edit

Comment: hmmm maybe, not sure because you can't post required code, only code snipped, to try to wrap that into invokeLater() as discused here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966287/dynamically-change-jbutton-icon/7966850#7966850

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using [Layered panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). I used one pane to display buffered image and next pane to listen Mouse and Keyboard events.

Answer (score 2):

Use [KeyBindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of [KeyListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), example for something similair is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940173/how-do-i-use-keyeventdispatcher/7940227#7940227)

The reason for this is how events are handled by Swing. You need a widget with focus for `KeyListener` to work - without focus, any `KeyListener`s are ignored (otherwise, typing would add to all `TextField`s in your UI instead of only the one with the focus).

The raw `KeyBindings` API doesn't care about focus - if no child window processes the event, the listener will be called.

Comment: I don't have problem handling the events. I just want to add the listener to the image somehow.

Comment: I updated the answer to make the difference between a KeyListener and a KeyBinding more obvious.

Comment: +1, for the key bindings. @aneal yes you will have a problem because labels don't get focus so a key event won't be generated.

Comment: I think its hard to understand. If i am not wrong KeyBinding is used for individuals key, but i am trying to get keycode of each pressed key irrespective of what key is pressed. So how can i do that with KeyBinding?

Answer (score 2):

Add the MouseListener to the label. Use Key Bindings for the key events.