# Dynamically change jButton icon

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a program that detects when certain machines are online and creates a button with a green "online" icon to show this. I want to add the functionality to check periodically if this machine is still online, and if it's not, change the icon to the "offline" icon that I've already defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I know how to set the icon, however I can't figure out a way to do it
> once the button has already been displayed

probably you have issues with [Concurency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), that means that all Swing code must be done on EDT

then you have to wrap `myButton.setIcon(myIcon)` to the `invokeLater()`, for example

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myButton.setIcon(myIcon);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

> I have a program that detects when certain machines are online and creates a button with a green "online" icon to show this.

Use a [`JToggleButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html) instead, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359906/swing-jtoolbarbutton-pressing/7360696#7360696)<sup>1</sup> & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743306/how-do-i-create-an-event-handler-for-a-jlabel/6743726#6743726)<sup>2</sup>.

> I can't figure out a way to do it once the button has already been displayed.

To toggle the state and fire an action event [`doClick()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#doClick%28%29) or alternately [`setSelected(boolean)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setSelected%28boolean%29).

### Screenshots

1. [image]
2. [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so using [AbstractButton.setIcon()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setIcon%28javax.swing.Icon%29).
It may require you to call `invalidate()` on the button to get the change displayed.

```
changeButton = new JButton(icon1);
changeButton.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener( )
    {
        private boolean flag = true;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent arg0 )
        {
            changeButton.setIcon( flag ? icon2 : icon1 );
            flag = !flag;
        }
    }
);
add(changeButton);
```

Comment: I know how to set the icon, however I can't figure out a way to do it once the button has already been displayed.

Comment: You can use this when the JButton is already drawn. I have added a code snippet to demonstrate this: a JButton that changes it's icon when it is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
btn1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/url.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add an action listener on the button, then in its called function change the icon - here is an example :

```
public yourDialogSwing() {

        Yourbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                onButtonPressed();
            }
        });
}

private void onButtonPressed() {
       YourButton.setIcon(YourButton.getPressedIcon());
}
```