# JButton's icon isn't changing (UNO card game)

Tags: java, swing, sockets, icons, jbutton

I'm implementing a UNO game using sockets and stuff. So far I've been working on the GUI for each client, I've succeeded when getting a random set of cards for each player and a random central card but got stuck on the following:
I'm using a  button to represent each card of a hand, say I want to select a Red card (because the central card is also Red) I've done all the validation methods that allow you to place or not to place your card. But the central button's icon isn't changing (the central card variable changes but not the button's icon that represents it).

I read this question and tried to use the SwingUtilities.invokeLater but the icon doesn't change ( [Dynamically change jButton icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966287/dynamically-change-jbutton-icon) ).

Here's the code where I change the JButton's icon:

```
public void setBtnIcon( final javax.swing.JButton btn,  final modelo.Card c) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btn.updateUI();
            Color color = c.getColor();
            btn.setBackground(color);
            if (c instanceof modelo.NumberCard) {
                short value = ((modelo.NumberCard) c).getValue();


                String str = Short.toString(value);
                btn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/jugadoruno/vista/" + str + ".png")));

            } else if (c instanceof modelo.ActionCard) {
                modelo.ActionType t = ((modelo.ActionCard) c).getActionType();
                String str = t.toString();

                btn.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/jugadoruno/vista/" + str + ".png")));

            }

        }
    });
}
```

It receives a card (to get it's color, value/actionType), it changes the JButton's background to that same color, and searches for the correct icon (if a card is red and has a value 1 it will change the Button's background to red and search for 1.png that is a transparent image with the number 1)

If there's a better way to doing this I'll be pleased to know it. Right now It just sets the icon at the beginning of the execution.
Thanks for your time!

[image: GUI]

Comment: You're most likely calling `updateUI()` needlessly. You should not need that unless the look and feel changes. Have you tried adding debugging output to to check the code you expect gets called and the correct icons get loaded properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Make sure you're calling `setBtnIcon` inside some kind of event listener such that it fires when you want it to. I couldn't tell from your original question whether "it just sets the icon at the beginning of execution" meant the method was only being called once.
2. Run through your code with a debugger (or add a print statement or two) to make sure that the result of `getClass().getResource(...)` isn't `null`. Getting co-located resources can be a tricky thing, especially if you're distributing your app in a JAR file.

Comment: Well this is the sequence i'm using: click the button->when clicked it calls a sendCard method which sends the card to server->server verifies if it can be placed and answers->if it can be placed, the server will send back that card->client receives card and change the "centralCard" variable (which is actually happening)-> BUT the button that is supposed to change when "centralCard" is updated, isn't changing it's icon

Comment: In that case, we'll need to see the code that is responsible for calling `setBtnIcon` when `centralCard` is updated. Sounds like there should be a change listener set up somewhere that handles that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the JButton "final" statement?

Comment: This is not an answer at all. You could add it as a comment in the OP's question section

Comment: Can't use non-final variables within invokeLater->run(); is there a solution to change them without being final? (I know it's not posible to change them being final)

Comment: You're not changing the contents of the `btn` variable itself, so don't worry about this suggestion. Changing the attributes of an object held in a `final` variable is fine.

Comment: Pardòn, i did not know that i had to say this in a comment (: i'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I wasn't calling the above function within the update function on the Observer, silly thing but true; thanks for your help, some of your answers were helpful.
the client window is the observer, when centralCard is changed, then I need to call the function I wrote above.

Comment: Sounds like what I suggested, then - in which case, not trying to nag, but accepting an answer gives both the answerer and the asker a small rep boost :).