# KeyAdapter listener works in Windows, not on Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, keylistener

I created a simple Nibbles (Snakes) game and everything works perfectly.

However, when I copy everything over to my mac (develop on a PC) and compile the same java files, the keyAdapter event listener for moving my snake around doesn't respond.

I'm not sure what is wrong.

here's the snippet, but if anyone would be willing to take a look at the whole program, I could send that privately. THANKS!

```
getThis().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()  {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {                    
            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                if(!glass.game.getDirection().equals("D"))
                    glass.game.setDirection("U");

            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                if(!glass.game.getDirection().equals("U"))
                    glass.game.setDirection("D");

            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                if(!glass.game.getDirection().equals("R"))
                    glass.game.setDirection("L");

            if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                if(!glass.game.getDirection().equals("L"))
                    glass.game.setDirection("R");
          }
});
```

Comment: General advice: Use Enums for directions, not strings.

Comment: "To fire keyboard events, a component must have the keyboard focus."—[*How to Write a Key Listener*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html).

Answer (score 6):

use `KeyBindings` instead of `KeyListener`, `KeyListener` isn't designated for listening `KeyEvents` in the Swing JComponents, this's listener for AWT Components, example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968)