# Java key bindings with multiple actions

Tags: java, macos, swing, key-bindings

So for reference, I am following [Trystan's roguelike tutorial for java](http://trystans.blogspot.hk/2011/08/roguelike-tutorial-02-input-output.html).

The tutorial above uses Key Listeners, which does not work for Mac OS X (and appears to be discouraged by the community), so I am trying to change the code to use Key Bindings instead.

Here's the question. In his "roguelike game", the game is divided into screens, where each screen has separate actions for a particular key. For instance, the "Start Screen" sends the player to the "Play screen" upon pressing the enter key:

```
public class StartScreen implements Screen {

    public void displayOutput(AsciiPanel terminal) {
        terminal.write("rl tutorial", 1, 1);
        terminal.writeCenter("-- press [enter] to start --", 22);
    }

    public Screen respondToUserInput(KeyEvent key) {
        return key.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ? new PlayScreen() : this;
    }
}
```

While the "Play Screen" sends the player to the "Win screen" upon pressing the enter key:

```
public class PlayScreen implements Screen {

    public void displayOutput(AsciiPanel terminal) {
        terminal.write("You are having fun.", 1, 1);
        terminal.writeCenter("-- press [escape] to lose or [enter] to win --", 22);
    }

    public Screen respondToUserInput(KeyEvent key) {
        switch (key.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: return new LoseScreen();
        case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER: return new WinScreen();
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Now, from what I can see from Key Bindings examples such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976166/java-difference-in-key-detection-between-windows-and-mac) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners), all the bindings and actions seem to be "dumped" into one class. This is unsatisfactory, because:

1. One keystroke leads to only one action (I suppose I could have the action do a switch case, and check what screen I am in, and then execute some code specific to said screen, but perhaps there is a better way.)
2. It becomes more difficult to determine what action is from/for what screen.

Would there be a way to get Key Bindings to have one keystroke execute different actions depending on the "Screen"? Would I just use conditionals? Can I put Key Binding logic in other classes (Screens) and then call them in the main class, like what is happening with Key Listeners above?

Comment: Couldn't you just register different bindings to each screen? Every component has it's own inputmap and actionmap

Comment: The program itself appears to have only one JFrame component (with the JFrame drawing different screens based on different conditions.)

Answer (score 2):

Key bindings are not necessarily dumped into one class.  They are associated with input maps, which in turn are associated with specific `JComponent`s.  If you register screen-specific bindings in the  `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` input map of the `JComponent` representing that screen, then they will be recognized when any component in that screen has the keyboard focus (supposing a component in between has not overridden the binding with its own), but not when a component in a different screen has the focus.

Overall, the system is very flexible.  You might consider reading [the Java Tutorial section on this topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to bring yourself up to speed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think the problem is how the game is setup; it has one JFrame and one AsciiPanel (JPanel) which simply changes display to show different screens. The "screens" are not JComponents so I can't directly put Key Bindings there, but perhaps I can just put a method that puts Key Bindings to the AsciiPanel itself. I'll see if that works.

Comment: You can change the registered key bindings when a different "screen" is displayed.  And if there really is no separate `JComponent` that can be associated with each logical screen overall, then perhaps it would make sense to create one.