# KeyListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Hello everyone I am new to Java so i think the answer to this question is very easy but I can't find out what part i'm doing wrong.. I added a keyListener to my pacman game but somehow it won't work.. i've used the following code:

```
package h04PacMan;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PacManBediening extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

private JButton links, rechts, boven, beneden;
PacMan pacman;

public PacManBediening(PacMan pacman) {

    this.pacman = pacman;

    links = new JButton("<");
    links.addActionListener(this);
    add(links);

    rechts = new JButton(">");
    rechts.addActionListener(this);
    add(rechts);

    boven = new JButton("^");
    boven.addActionListener(this);
    add(boven);

    beneden = new JButton("v");
    beneden.addActionListener(this);
    add(beneden);

}

/*
 * bediening bij een klik
 */

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == links) {

        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( -10 );
        pacman.setBesturing(0);
        pacman.setView(180);
        //System.out.println("links");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == rechts) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( +10 );
        pacman.setBesturing(0);
        pacman.setView(0);
        //System.out.println("rechts");
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == boven) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( -10);
        pacman.setBesturing(1);
        pacman.setView(90);
        //System.out.println("boven");
    }
    else {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( +10);
        pacman.setBesturing(1);
        pacman.setView(270);
        //System.out.println("beneden");
    }


}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( -10 );
        pacman.setBesturing(0);
        pacman.setView(180);
        System.out.println("links");
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( +10 );
        pacman.setBesturing(0);
        pacman.setView(0);
        System.out.println("rechts");
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( -10);
        pacman.setBesturing(1);
        pacman.setView(90);
        System.out.println("boven");
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        pacman.setRichtingEnSnelheid( +10);
        pacman.setBesturing(1);
        pacman.setView(270);
        System.out.println("beneden");
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

can someone tell me what to add or do different?

Comment: well if i use my arrow controls nothing happens and i also don't see the system.out.prinln I wrote under the controls so the whole method is not called i think

Comment: I can only guess. You need to add a key listener to the component that has focus, otherwise the event will not fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a couple of lines in your `PacManBediening` constructor.

```
this.pacman = pacman;
this.setFocusable(true);
this.addKeyListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks alot this were the lines i missed!

Answer (score 2):

- `KeyListener` isn't designated for `Swing JComponents`, I wouldn't going this way,
- I think there is simple and possible to lost the `Focus` from focusable `JComponents`
- use `KeyBindings` as most scallable workaround, rather that `"catching or hunting for Focus"` for `KeyListener`
- for `Swing JComponents` are all internal short_cuts, key shortcuts, built_in methods, notifiers, based on `KeyBindings`
- [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968)

Comment: as i mentioned i am new to Java so I am just trying stuff out by creating this pacman game. I experienced the problem of KeyListener and I took a look at the code example but I can't understand everything that is in the code yet so I don't know what it does or what parts are relevant yet.. :(

Comment: @Reshad no problem with you nor personally, my answer here is to ---> `can someone tell me what to add or do different?`

Comment: ah I understand! :) well I will try to redesign my code to work with keyBindings but can't promise it'll work!