# keyReleased function not restoring original Background color in java

Tags: java, swing, key, jbutton, keylistener

When I press a key for some time, the background color of the key doesn't restore to original color in keyReleased function.What am I doing wrong. If you could redirect me to some site contain tutorial on how to make programs like this with examples, it will be very helpful. Here is the code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
    {
        int code= event.getKeyCode();
        String x,h;

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            s=names[i];
            x=s.trim();

            if(x.contentEquals(event.getKeyText(code)) )
            {
                backColor=but[i].getBackground();
                but[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                break;
            }
        }
        switch(event.getKeyCode())
        {
        case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SLASH:
            h=" \\ ";
            for(int i=0;i<but.length;i++)
            {
                if(h.contentEquals(but[i].getText()))
                {
                    backColor=but[i].getBackground();
                    but[i].setBackground(Color.RED);
                    buttonIndex=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
    {
        String x;
        int code= event.getKeyCode();

        for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
        {
            s=names[i];
            x=s.trim();

            if(x.contentEquals(event.getKeyText(code)) && !s.contentEquals("                             "))
            {System.out.println("outside");
                but[i].setBackground(backColor);
                break;
            }
            else
                if(s.contentEquals("                             "))
                {
                    but[buttonIndex].setBackground(backColor);
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: please this question is about, (deepest coded in Navajo) question on this week,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- don't use [`Keylistener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for `Swing JComponents`, [use `KeyBindings` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940173/how-do-i-use-keyeventdispatcher/7940227#7940227)
- your `JFrame`, `JPanel`, `JComponent` must be focusable (`setFocusable`)
- in one moment only one of `JComponent` can be focusable, then your program will be `focus_hunter` this not caused [by using KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)
- for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable