# Java keylisteners don't do anything but the program still runs

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener

The keylisteners are supposed to move the block up and down but when the keys (w, s) are pressed or held they do nothing.
Here is the code (I'm omitting the other class which has nothing to do with the problem)

Thank you for your time

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    public void Draw()
    {
        Handler handle = new Handler();
        f.addKeyListener(handle);
        f.setFocusable(true);
        f.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(400, 250);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class Handler extends JFrame implements KeyListener
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S))
            {
                System.out.println("testw");
            }
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W))
            {
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP))
            {
            }
            if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even display the JFrame that has the KeyListeners in it. It creates another JFrame entirely in the main method.

Comment: ... nor is `draw()` ever called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) ([all Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)) by default never to react to [KeyEvent from KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), then isn't possible to add `KeyListener` to `JFrame`, use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead
- you can to add [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to [JPanel (JPanel.setFocusable(true))](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html), but use `KeyBindings` in this case too
- `KeyListener` is correct listener for `Keys Shortcuts` for three or more `KeyPressed` in the same time
- [code example about KeyBindings based on @HFOE code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940173/how-do-i-use-keyeventdispatcher/7940227#7940227)