# Cannot move a JLabel with the arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, keylistener

So I'm trying to make a JLabel ("player") move 10 px in a direction I choose as you can see in the code below, but I just can't make it work. I've run it and pressed an arrow key but nothing happened so I was hoping you guys could help me ^^.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel player = new JLabel();
    JLabel separator = new JLabel();
    JLabel object = new JLabel();

    public Main() {

        setSize(400, 500);
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("BenTY");

        separator.setOpaque(true);
        separator.setBackground(Color.black);
        separator.setBounds(0, 400, 400, 1);
        add(separator);

        player.setBackground(Color.black);
        player.setOpaque(true);
        player.setBounds(195, 390, 10, 10);
        player.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
            {
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
                {
                    player.setBounds(player.getX(), player.getY()+10, 10, 10);
                    repaint();
                }
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                {
                    player.setLocation(player.getX(), player.getY() - 10);
                    repaint();
                }
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
                {
                    player.setLocation(player.getX()-10,player.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
                if(ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
                {
                    player.setLocation(player.getX()+10,player.getY());
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        add(player);

        Random random = new Random();
        int oLocationX = random.nextInt(40) * 10;
        int oLocationY = random.nextInt(40) * 10;
        object.setBackground(Color.red);
        object.setOpaque(true);
        object.setBounds(oLocationX, oLocationY, 10, 10);
        add(object);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main ui = new Main();
        ui.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

BTW sorry for poor coding :D

Comment: `BTW sorry for poor coding :D`: Using consistent bracket placement (same line vs next line) would be a nice start towards more beautiful code. Otherwise, don't excuse for it! You're here to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- you would need to use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of low_level [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- Player (be sure that all [JComponents) need to be setFocusable() for KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), otherwise `KeyListener` doesn't works, its need the Focus in the Components tree
- [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968)