# How do I make a rectangle move across the screen with key bindings?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paint

The game I'm trying to create is snake and so far I've figured out how to use `paint(Graphics g)` a bit of `JPanel`, mouse listener and now I'm trying to create a rectangle that will move across the screen and use key bindings or key listener, but I have no idea how I should go about this.

Here's my code so far, it has 2 parts.
The first part is called `snake2` because if I don't know what I'm doing I make the same program with different things. `Snake` used frame, but `Snake2` uses `JPanel` (looks better…)

```
    import java.awt.*;

    //required for MouseListener
    import java.awt.event.*;

    //requied for Graohics
    import java.applet.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Snake2 extends JPanel
    {
      private Rectangle sampleObject;

      public Snake2()
      {
         addMouseListener(new MouseListener());

      }


      /* create background */
      public void paint (Graphics g)
      {
        Font angel = new Font("Angelic War", Font.BOLD, 60);
        Font ith = new Font("Ithornît", Font.BOLD, 78);

        setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
        g.fillRect(0,0,700,850);
        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRect(50,150,600,650);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawRect(50,150,600,650);

        g.drawString("Quit",52,116);
        g.drawRect(50,100,30,20);

        //g.setFont(angel);
        //g.drawString("SNAKE",300,70);
        g.setFont(ith);
        g.drawString("SNAKE",280,90);  
      }

      public void sprite (int x, int y, Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(300,200,10,10);
      }

      public void start (int x, int y, Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString("START GAME",300,425);
      }
    }


    /* Tracks where mouse is clicked */
    class MouseListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me)
      {
        if (me.getX() >= 50 && me.getX() <= 80 && me.getY() >= 100 && me.getY() <= 120)
        {
          System.exit(0);
        }

          String str="Mouse Released at "+me.getX()+","+me.getY();
          System.out.println(str);
      }
    }
```

And the second part is:

```
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.Dimension;

    public class SnakeDisplay
    {

      public static void main ( String [ ] arguments )
      {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( "Snake" );
        Snake2 panel = new Snake2 ( );


        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add ( panel );
        frame.setContentPane ( panel );

        frame.setPreferredSize ( new Dimension ( 700, 850 ) );
        //frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
        frame.pack ( );     
      }
    }
```

Comment: What specifically are you asking? How to loop over some game logic so the snake moves?

Comment: See if [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) tutorial answers your questions.

Comment: This question has potential if you reword it to be more specific but right now it's in danger of being closed. I think it could be recovered though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should override `paintComponent` in your `JPanel` and call `super.paintComponent(g)` in it.
2. See [How to Use Key Bindings tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Key bindings are preffered in this case rather than a `KeyListener`
3. `pack()` *then* `setVisible()`
4. You should set global variables for x anf y location, so they can be accessed from within your `Action`. Then in your actions, increment your x or y and repaint

Try running this example

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBidings extends JFrame {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

    public KeyBidings(){
        Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                x +=10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        };

            InputMap inputMap = drawPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
        actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);

        add(drawPanel);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {


        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 200);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new KeyBidings();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Here's the code you're more concerned with

```
    Action rightAction = new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x +=10;
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
    };

    InputMap inputMap = drawPanel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap actionMap = drawPanel.getActionMap();

    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "rightAction");
    actionMap.put("rightAction", rightAction);
```

Create a custom action and add that action to the action map, linked to the input map keystroke.  In the action, just increment or, decrement the x and/or y, depending on the direction, then repaint the panel.

---

**See** [Key binding tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) | [Graphics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: @Muhammad I just used [CamStudio](http://camstudio.org/) to capture the screen video, then import the avi to photoshop and save for web as a gif

Comment: +1   [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940173/how-do-i-use-keyeventdispatcher/7940227#7940227), note you forgot to mentioned or to set focus for JComponent to InputMap

Comment: does paint over write paint component? because whenever I use both paint component is not visible

Comment: actually never mind my earlier comment. How do you add a background because I can't get paint and paintComponent to show at the same time

Comment: Whar kind of background? An image?

Comment: @user3146998 I edited my code a little bit. If you look in the `paintComponent` you will see `g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());`. Also can you accept this answer if it worked for you. It's the check mark.