# Java - How to move a rectangle that's drawn by Graphics2D?

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to move a rectangle drawn by Graphics2D over, but it just doesn't work. When I do x += 1; It actually moves it 1 pixel over and stops. if I do say, x += 200; It moves it 200 pixels over ONCE not in every update, but ONCE.

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(x, 350, 50, 50);

    x += 1;
}
```

int x is called outside void paint to make sure it's not incremented as 150 each time.
Draws fine, just doesn't move, I tried using a thread and using a while loop so while the thread is running, it moves, but no luck.

Comment: Post more code for us

Comment: How do you trigger `repaint()`?

Comment: Take a look at [**How do I move a rectangle accross the screen using key bindingd**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20844242/2587435). It should help you out.

Comment: Holy! Thanks i just forgot to do this.repaint(); Probably the worst mistake in java history.

Comment: Where is x created? Your code sample is incomplete.

Comment: "int x is called outside void paint to make sure it's not incremented as 150 each time" Read next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a while loop or a different thread, you should be using a `java.swing.Timer` for animation. Here's the basic construct

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

where delay is the time you want to be delayed between repaints, and `listener` is the listener with the callback function to perform. You could do something like this, where you change the `x` location, then call `repaint();`

```
    ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (x >= D_W) {
                x = 0;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            } else {
                x += 10;
                drawPanel.repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(250, listener);
    timer.start();
```

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class KeyBindings extends JFrame {

    private static final int D_W = 500;
    private static final int D_H = 200;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

    public KeyBindings() {
        ActionListener listener = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (x >= D_W) {
                    x = 0;
                    drawPanel.repaint();
                } else {
                    x += 10;
                    drawPanel.repaint();
                }
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(100, listener);
        timer.start();
        add(drawPanel);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);
        }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(D_W, D_H);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new KeyBindings();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Here's a running example

Comment: Is it possible to use an image instead of this rectangle? I tried it with g.drawImage(...) but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use Affine Transformations. By simply using the AffineTransform class you can translate the graphics object along the screen on the x or y axis.

Here is a link with info on the class and its functions etc.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html

Here is another website that will give you examples on translation as well as other transformations: http://zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/transformations/

And when incrementing x or y to translate, you must call the `repaint()` function to repaint the graphics object.