# make them move and synchronize

Tags: java, swing, graphics, keylistener, synchronized

I'm trying to make a graphic move through the panel but I have others in a moving wire from side to side the first problem is not synchronized and the second does not move anyone knows how to make it sincronize if I do threads separate and make it move  thanks

```
public class caminos extends JPanel implements Runnable {
    int x1 = 0;
    int y1 = 50;
    int x2 = 400;
    int y2 = 150;
    int x3 = 0;
    int y3 = 250;
    int x = 200;
    int y = 350;
    int velX = 3;
    int velXX = -3;
    public boolean corren = true;
    Thread threadprincipal;

    caminos() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 420));
        addKeyListener(new personaje(this));

        threadprincipal = new Thread(this);
        threadprincipal.start();

    }

    public void up() {
        y = y - 3;
    }

    public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 460, 450);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(x1, y1, 40, 40);

        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(x2, y2, 40, 40);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect(x3, y3, 40, 40);

    }// this is the problem is not synchronized and does not move

    private synchronized void render() {

        Graphics g;
        g = this.getGraphics();

        if (g != null) {
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            g.fillRect(x, y, 30, 30);

            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        }
    }

    public void run() {

        while (corren) {
            render();

            x1 = x1 + velX;
            x3 = x3 + velX;
            x2 = x2 + velXX;

            if (x1 < 0 || x1 > 400) {
                velX = -velX;
            }

            if (x2 <= 0 || x2 > 400) {
                velXX = -velXX;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            //
            repaint();
        }
        // x1=x1+velX;
        // x3=x3+velX;
        // x2=x2-3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame ven = new JFrame();
        ven.setSize(460, 430);
        ven.setTitle("game");
        ven.add(new caminos());
        ven.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ven.setVisible(true);
    }

    // another class to move
    class personaje implements KeyListener {

        caminos game;

        personaje(caminos passjuego) {
            game = passjuego;
        }

        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                game.up();
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should tag this with whatever programming language you're using here.

Comment: There should NEVER be a need to synchronise the paintComponent method, as you should never be calling it directly. The paint process is controlled by the RepaintManager and Event Dispatching Thread, meaning the a paint cycle should only ever be controlled by the EDT...

Comment: You should never have a need to use getGraphics, this is not how custom painting is done in Swing, instead, issue a repaint request back to the RepaintManager (via the repaint method). In 15 years of Swing development, if never used Toolkit.sync. In your example, paintComponent will override anything that is painted by the render method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of `Runnable#Thread` stopped by `Thread.sleep(int)`
- read about [Java Naming Convention](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)
- override `getPreferredSize` for [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) instead of `setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 420));`
- all coordinates inside `paintComponent` are accesible by `getHeight`/`Wieght`
- use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)
- otherwise you (enable `KeyEvents` for `Container`) have to `setFocusable()` for `JPanel`,
- 1st. code line should be `super.paintComponent` inside `public synchronized void paintComponent(Graphics g) {`
- you can't to code `g = this.getGraphics()`;, everything could be done `paintComponent`
- see [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)
- use `JFrame.pack();` instead of `ven.setSize(460, 430)`; in the case that you overrode `getPreferredSize` for [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)
- `Thread.sleep(10);`

  a) very short delay overloading latency in Native OS

  b) block [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), I'd suggest again to use Swing Timer instead
- by put everything (exluding Swing Timer) together - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940173/how-do-i-use-keyeventdispatcher/7940227#7940227)